# Does Rust have an idiomatic equivalent to F# typedefs?

Tags: types, rust, type-alias

I'm re-writing existing code of mine in Rust 1.6 and I've found it very convenient in the source language to label a type by typedef. For example, in my card game I have a rank value in F# defined as:

```
type Rank = uint8
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) section titled [Creating Type Synonyms with Type Aliases](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#creating-type-synonyms-with-type-aliases):

Rust provides the ability to declare a *type alias* to give an existing type another name. For this we use the `type` keyword. For example, we can create the alias `Kilometers` to `i32` like so:

```
type Kilometers = i32;
```

Now, the alias `Kilometers` is a synonym for `i32`; [...], `Kilometers` is not a separate, new type. Values that have the type `Kilometers` will be treated the same as values of type `i32`:

```
type Kilometers = i32;

let x: i32 = 5;
let y: Kilometers = 5;

println!("x + y = {}", x + y);
```

There's more that you should read, but this answers the question.

---

As a bit of editorial, I don't think that a type alias is a great fit in a lot of places that people use them. Assuming that your `Rank` type represents something to do with a deck of cards, I'd suggest either an [`enum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html) or a [*newtype*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-for-type-safety-and-abstraction). The reason is that with a type alias you can do something like this:

```
let rank: Rank = 100;
```

Which is nonsensical for a typical deck of cards. An enum is a restricted set. This means you can never create an invalid `Rank`:

```
enum Rank {
    One, Two, Three, Four, Five,
    Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten,
    Jack, Queen, King, Ace,
}

impl Rank {
    fn from_value(v: u8) -> Result<Rank, ()> {
        use Rank::*;

        let r = match v {
            1 => One,
            2 => Two,
            // ...
            _ => return Err(()),
        };
        Ok(r)
    }

    fn value(&self) -> u8 {
        use Rank::*;

        match *self {
            One => 1,
            Two => 2,
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

A *newtype* is just a wrapper type. It consumes no extra space compared to the wrapped type, it just provides an actual new type that lets you implement methods that can restrict to valid values. It's possible to create invalid values, but only within your own code, not all client code:

```
struct Rank(u8);

impl Rank {
    fn from_value(v: u8) -> Result<Rank, ()> {
        if v >= 1 && v <= 14 {
            Ok(Rank(v))
        } else {
            Err(())
        }
    }

    fn value(&self) -> u8 {
        self.0
    }
}
```

I tend to use type aliases as quick placeholders of types. While writing the above examples, I actually wrote:

```
type Error = ();
```

And returned a `Result<Rank, Error>`, but then thought that would be confusing. :-)

The other case I use them is to shorten a larger type that I don't want to hide. This happens with types like iterators or `Result`s, which you can [see in the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html). Something like:

```
type CardResult<T> = Result<T, Error>;

fn foo() -> CardResult<String> {
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick  and detailed reply! Normally I'd very much agree with you on using enums to restrict my values to the standard deck values. However, in my case I use the term "card" generically, and not playing card, so I need a rank of unspecified value.

Am I understanding correctly that I should use a type alias if I want simple substitution, and a newtype if I'd like to impose additional restrictions / logic?

Comment: @ErikUggeldahl yes, that sounds correct. A newtype allows additional restrictions or logic, while an alias is just that, another name for the same thing.

Comment: @ErikUggeldahl it's not only restricting values. An alias provides no additional type safety because it's not a... new type, but another name for the same type. Does it make sense for you to be able to calculate a `Rank / 5` or pass a `Rank` to a function that takes a `u8`? Because a type alias allows you to do that (since `Rank` *is* a `u8`). What you typically use type aliases for in Rust is for convenience when you have a very long and complex type and want to refer to it more concisely (but the alias *is* the type and should be used in lieu of it everywhere)