# Does Rust have an equivalent of C's typedef?

Tags: types, rust, type-alias

C offers the keyword `typedef` which lets you alias another type:

```c
typedef unsigned int uint;
```

This basically makes `uint` an alias for `unsigned int`. This also works with more complex types and structures too. Does Rust have a similar language feature? If yes, how are typedefs handled in Rust?

Comment: [Relevant section from the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#type-aliases-create-type-synonyms)

Comment: [Does Rust have an idiomatic equivalent to F# typedefs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34938429/155423)

Comment: @E_net4 Thank you.

Comment: You might also want to look up [the Newtype Pattern](https://aturon.github.io/features/types/newtype.html).  There is zero runtime cost, and it enables you to implement traits, member functions, and such on preexisting types.

Comment: [updated link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-to-implement-external-traits-on-external-types) for newtype pattern

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes. You can simply write

```
type MyInt = i32;
```

These are aliases at the name level, i.e. it is absolutely immaterial which name for the same type you then use. They are perfectly interchangeable.

Comment: But Rust only creates type aliases, not new types. If two aliases share the same underlying type, their instances can be cross-assigned, as well as comparisons in if clauses are allowed. C doesn't allow such comparisons.

Comment: @Ugur C's typedef's are exactly the same.

Comment: You're right, I mixed it up with complex struct typedefs.