# How can you create nominal typing for primitives without struct wrappering?

Tags: rust

I have two different kinds of floats, `Latitude` and `Longitude`. How can I create nominal types for these different floats such that assigning a `f32` variable with a semantic meaning of `Longitude` to a variable with a type and semantic meaning of `Latitude` is an error?  Can I do this *without* a struct wrappering the primitive type?

```
type Longitude = f32;
type Latitude = f32;

fn main() {
    let lng : Longitude = 42.0;
    let lat : Latitude = lng; // <-- goal is a type error
    println!("lat={}, lng={}", lat, lng);
}
```

How can I create nominal types for Rust primitives?

Comment: Seems like this is, if not *exactly* a duplicate, well-answered by [Does Rust have an idiomatic equivalent to F# typedefs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34938429/364696), which makes it clear that `type` won't do what you want, and a *newtype* `struct` wrapper (or `enum` for cases with restricted values) is the only reasonable solution. Shepmaster put a *lot* of detail into [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34938493/364696) describing the hows and whys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Rust have an idiomatic equivalent to F# typedefs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938429/does-rust-have-an-idiomatic-equivalent-to-f-typedefs)

Comment: Thank you guys.   So it does look like a wrapper struct is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer based on [Shepmaster's excellent answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34938493/364696): You can't. You have to make a `struct` and define converters to/from that new `struct` and the underlying type it supports (the converters won't go two steps, so two types compatible with `f32` won't convert to each other directly).

For example:

```
struct Latitude(f32);

impl Latitude {
    fn from_value(v: f32) -> Result<Latitude, ()> {
        if v >= -90.0 && v <= 90.0 {
            Ok(Latitude(v))
        } else {
            Err(())
        }
    }

    fn value(&self) -> f32 {
        self.0
    }
}
```

It might seem like pointless boilerplate, but in this case, it does provide the added advantage of ensuring the values are sane, where a latitude above 90 degrees is nonsensical, and should rightly be rejected on construction.

Answer (score 0):

If ShadowRanger's answer is turned into a macro, it could look like:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::fmt;

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! Nominal {
    ($type_name: ident, $t: path) => {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        struct $type_name($t);
        impl Deref for $type_name {
            type Target = $t;
            fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
                &self.0
            }
        }

        impl From<$t> for $type_name {
            fn from(value: $t) -> Self {
                Self(value)
            }
        }

        impl From<&$type_name> for $type_name {
            fn from(value: &$type_name) -> Self {
                Self((*value).clone())
            }
        }

        impl fmt::Display for $type_name {
            fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                write!(f, "{}({})", std::stringify!($type_name), self.0)
            }
        }

    }
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! NominalNum {
    ($type_name: ident, $t: path) => {

        Nominal!($type_name, $t);

        impl std::ops::Sub for $type_name {
            type Output = Self;
            fn sub(self, other: Self) -> Self {
                Self::from(*self - *other)
            }
        }

        impl std::ops::Sub<$t> for $type_name {
            type Output = Self;
            fn sub(self, other: $t) -> Self {
                Self::from(*self - other)
            }
        }

        impl std::ops::Add for $type_name {
            type Output = Self;
            fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self {
                Self::from(*self + *other)
            }
        }

        impl std::ops::Add<$t> for $type_name {
            type Output = Self;
            fn add(self, other: $t) -> Self {
                Self::from(*self + other)
            }
        }
    }
}

NominalNum!(Lat, f32);
NominalNum!(LatDelta, f32);
NominalNum!(Lng, f32);
NominalNum!(LngDelta, f32);

fn main() {

    let lat1 = Lat::from(45.0);
    let lat2 = Lat::from(46.0);

    let lng1 = Lng::from(-120.0);
    let lng2 = Lng::from(-121.0);

    let lat_delta = lat2 - lat1;
    let lng_delta = lng2 - lng1;

    println!("lat_delta={lat_delta} lng_delta={lng_delta}");

    let lat3 = Lat::from(54.75);
    let lng3 = Lng::from(-4.08);
    let lat_delta_literal = lat3 - 42.0;
    let lng_delta_literal = lng3 - 42.0;
    println!("lat_delta_literal={lat_delta_literal} lng_delta_literal={lng_delta_literal}");

    // let bad_delta = lat2 - lng1;
    // error[E0277]: cannot subtract `Lng` from `Lat`
    //   --> src/main.rs:97:26
    //    |
    // 97 |     let bad_delta = lat2 - lng1;
    //    |                          ^ no implementation for `Lat - Lng`
    //    |
    //    = help: the trait `Sub<Lng>` is not implemented for `Lat`
    //    = help: the following other types implement trait `Sub<Rhs>`:
    //              <Lat as Sub<f32>>
    //              <Lat as Sub>
}
```

Which yields:

```
lat_delta=Lat(1) lng_delta=Lng(-1)
lat_delta_literal=Lat(12.75) lng_delta_literal=Lng(-46.08)
```

Clearly a delta between a Latitude and a Longitude is its own derivative type, but maybe this is getting closer.